# Ho to install libifport.so.5 in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: apt

I run an executable file and I get this error:

error while loading shared libraries: libifport.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I can find the library to install it.

Someone can help?

Cheers
Vasco

Comment: What is the executable, and how did you install it? Is the Intel Fortran compiler installed on your system?

Comment: I have gfortran but not intel Fortran

Comment: As far as I can tell, `libifport.so` is part of the [Intel Fortran redistributable libraries](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-compilers-redistributable-libraries-by-version.html). You may need to contact the software's vendor to find out which version you need and how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the problem for me on Debian 9:
`conda install -c intel -c conda-forge -c pytorch --override-channels intel-fortran-rt`

```
# find / -iname "libifport*"
./opt/conda/lib/libifport.so
./opt/conda/lib/libifport.so.5
./opt/conda/pkgs/intel-fortran-rt-2021.3.0-intel_3350/lib/libifport.so
./opt/conda/pkgs/intel-fortran-rt-2021.3.0-intel_3350/lib/libifport.so.5
```